# Is there anyway to fetch tags of a RDS instance using boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, boto3

```
rds_client = boto3.client('rds', 'us-east-1')
instance_info = rds_client.describe_db_instances( DBInstanceIdentifier='**myinstancename**')
```

But the instance_info doesn't contain any tags I set in the RDS instance. I want to fetch the instances that has env='production' in them and want to exclude env='test'. Is there any method in boto3 that fetched the tags as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only through boto3.client("rds").[list_tags_for_resource](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Client.list_tags_for_resource)

> Lists all tags on an Amazon RDS resource.
>   ResourceName (string) --
>   The Amazon RDS resource with tags to be listed. This value is an Amazon Resource Name (ARN). For information about creating an ARN, see Constructing an RDS Amazon Resource Name (ARN) .

```
import boto3
rds_client = boto3.client('rds', 'us-east-1')
db_instance_info = rds_client.describe_db_instances(
    DBInstanceIdentifier='**myinstancename**')

for each_db in db_instance_info['DBInstances']: 
    response = rds_client.list_tags_for_resource(
    ResourceName=each_db['DBInstanceArn'],
    Filters=[{
            'Name': 'env',
            'Values': [
                'production',
            ]
        }])
```

Either use a simple exclusion over the simple filter, or you can dig through the documentation to build complicated JMESPath filter using 
[paginators](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/paginators.html).

Notes : AWS resource tags is not a universal implementation. So you must always refer to the boto3 documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Figured it out earlier. :)

Answer (score 0):

Python program will show you how to list all rds instance, there type and status.
**`list_rds_instances.py`**

```
import boto3

#connect ot rds instance
client = boto3.client('rds')

#rds_instance will have all rds information in dictionary.
rds_instance = client.describe_db_instances()

all_list = rds_instance['DBInstances']

print('RDS Instance Name \t| Instance Type \t| Status')

for i in rds_instance['DBInstances']:
    dbInstanceName = i['DBInstanceIdentifier']
    dbInstanceEngine = i['DBInstanceClass']
    dbInstanceStatus = i['DBInstanceStatus']
    print('%s \t| %s \t| %s' %(dbInstanceName, dbInstanceEngine, dbInstanceStatus))
```

**Important Note:** While working with boto3 you need to setup your credentials in two files **`~/.aws/credentials`** and **`~/.aws/config`**

```
~/.aws/credentials
[default]
aws_access_key_id=<ACCESS_KEY>
aws_secret_access_key=<SECRET_KEY>

~/.aws/config
[default]
region=ap-south-1
```